# Spring throws "Unterminated &lt;form:select tag" exception when adding a conditional expression

Tags: spring, select, tags, expression

Finally solved.
Thanks to @geoand I'v made a small change and it works.

```
<form:select path="associationAbroad" disabled="${candidate.associationAbroadNameSelected ? 'false' : 'true'}" >
```

**This is my original post**:

The condition/s work well inside other tags like div or span and even inside a clear `<select>` tag but when i use it inside form:select it throws exception.

candidate.associationAbroadNameSelected = true or false as boolean primitive.

I'm using Spring MVC 3.2.5

please help.

```
<!-- This one works --> 
<select ${candidate.associationAbroadNameSelected ? "enabled" : "disabled"}>
    <option value="2">test</option>
</select>
```

.

```
<!-- This one throws exception that blows my mind :-( -->
<form:select path="associationAbroad" ${candidate.associationAbroadNameSelected ? "enabled" : "disabled"} >
    <form:option value="">Select...</form:option>
</form:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use XHTML syntax instead of HTML 5 and see what happens

```
<form:select path="associationAbroad" disabled=${candidate.associationAbroadNameSelected ? "enabled" : "disabled"} >
<form:option value="">Select...</form:option>
</form:select>
```

Comment: it is a regular option tag. syntax fixed.

Comment: It won't work as adding disabled property is enough to disable the tag and no matter what value comes with it.
I tested it here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_disabled

Comment: It works with a small change. I've edited my post. Thank you @geoand.

Answer (score 0):

Even more simple:

```
<form:select path="associationAbroad" disabled="${!candidate.associationAbroadNameSelected}" >
```